# Find when a cylinder begins rolling without slipping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram

I am preparing for an exam and came across the following problem. I am told a cylinder is thrown with horizontal speed $v_1$ on a surface with friction coefficient $\mu$. I am asked to determine the speed of the cylinder right as it begins rolling without slipping. The following is the image attached to the problem:

[image]

I am first confused by the rolling direction shown on the diagram. Is it a mistake? I would think the cylinder would be rolling on the opposite direction. Anyway, I was unable to progress much in solving the problem myself, as I don't have a good grasp on these particular contents yet. Checking both of the possible answers I am left with many questions. The first answer defines the following equations to solve the problem:

$$-f_r = ma$$
$$f_rr = I\alpha$$

Which lead to my first question. Why is friction considered to cause a positive torque, when it evidently would cause the cylinder to roll in the negative $\theta$ direction? They even attach the following explanation:

[image]

Why do they say torque is negative inertia times $\alpha$? Anyway, they later find the relation between $\alpha$ and $a$ to solve the problem. I tried solving it by setting $-f_rr = I\alpha$, but that gives an erroneous answer. Why is that the case?

The next solution I like a lot more, and it involves the use of angular momentum with respect to any point in the ground, but I still need some clarification. They first claim that, because there is no torque with respect to the floor, angular momentum is conserved. They then claim that the initial angular momentum with respect to the floor is simply $-Rmv_0 \hat{k}$, which makes sense. The final angular momentum is calculated as the sum of the angular momentum caused by the linear momentum of the cylinder, $-Rmv_1 \hat{k}$ and the 'formulaic' angular momentum of the cylinder, $-I\omega_1\hat{k}$. They then solve the resulting equation using the fact $r\omega_1 = v_1$.

I want to understand how the final angular momentum was calculated, both in this situation and in general situations.

Comment: The direction of the angular velocity is inconsistent with the initial velocity as you note.  Before placing the cylinder on the floor, it doesn't have an angular velocity.  Once you place it on the floor, the friction (which is in the opposite direction as $v$) provides it a negative, i.e., clockwise torque.  This results in a negative angular acceleration $α$ and a negative $ω$.  The friction is a constant, so $α$ is a constant as well.  So $ω$ begins increasing to the point where the rolling without slipping condition $v = ω R$ is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can conserve angular momentum of the cylinder about the contact points because torque of friction about it is zero as friction passes through it.
$mvr = Iω$
$mvr = 3mr²/2 *ω$
$v = 3/2 *v'$
$v' = 2/3* v $
$$OR$$
We can also solve it by writing the equations of motion:
$v' = ωr $
$F*r = mr²/2*α$
$F = mr/2 * α$
$2μg/r = α$
$v-μgt = v'$
$αt = ω$
On solving, we get:
 $v' = 2/3*v$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really liked your first solution. I don't understand your second solution as well though. Why does friction create positive torque?